# `raise_if_conflicts' when running migration with rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run the maintenance application with oldest rails version '2.3.18'. and ree-1.8.7-2012.02 [ x86_64 ]. `bundle install` and `rake db:create` are working fine, and when I run `rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Could not find table 'comments'
```

With Comments I have 3 dependent tables, so I did:

```
ruby script/generate migration CreateComments commentable_type:string commentable_id:integer body:text member_id:integer created_at:datettime
```

and when I run `rake db:migrate`. I am get this error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1613:in `raise_if_conflicts': can't activate oauth-0.4.7, already activated oauth-0.3.6 (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:740:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1209:in `gem'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/plugins/oauth-plugin/rails/init.rb:1:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/config/environment.rb:15
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /root/Desktop/Projects/community/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/generate.rb:1
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from script/generate:3
```

In my Gemfile, I have the following line:

```
gem 'oauth', '0.3.6'
```

Comment: I think some gem have dependency for oauth-0.4.7 or greater version. Please check Gemfile.lock

Comment: In Gemfile.lock it is `oauth (0.4.7)`, so I changed in the Gemfile as `gem 'oauth', '0.4.7'` and run bundle install but no luck. The error is coming when i am adding the above table and running rake db:migrate.

Comment: uninstall   "gem uninstall oauth-0.3.6"  version

Comment: It is saying gem "oauth-0.3.6" is not installed

Answer (score 0):

Can you please run your rake command like below:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Let me know if it works or not. Thanks